# What happens when redis gets overloaded?

Tags: redis

If redis gets overloaded, can I configure it to drop set requests? I have an application where data is updated in real time (10-15 times a second per item) for a large number of items. The values are outdated quickly and I don't need any kind of consistency.

I would also like to compute parallel sum of the values that are written in real time. What's the best option here? LUA executed in redis? Small app located on the same box as redis using UNIX sockets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Redis gets overloaded it will just slow down its clients. For most commands, the protocol itself is synchronous.

Redis supports pipelining though, but there is no way a client can cancel the traffic still in the pipeline, but not yet acknowledged by the server. Redis itself does not really queue the incoming traffic, the TCP stack does it.

So it is not possible to configure the Redis server to drop set requests. However, it is possible to implement a last value queue on client side:

- the queue is actually a represented by 2 maps indexed by your items (only one value stored per item). The primary map will be used by the application. The secondary map will be used by a specific thread. The 2 maps content can be swapped in an atomic way.
- a specific thread is blocking when the primary map is empty. When it is not, it swaps the content of the two maps, sends the content of the secondary map asynchronously to Redis using aggressive pipelining and variadic parameters commands. It also receives ack from Redis.
- while the thread is working with the secondary map, the application can still fill the primary map. If Redis is too slow, the application will only accumulate last values in the primary map.

This strategy could be implemented in C with hiredis and the event loop of your choice.

However, it is not trivial to implement, so I would first check if the performance of Redis against *all* the traffic is not enough for my purpose. It is not uncommon to benchmark Redis at more than 500K op/s these days (using a single core). Nothing prevents you to shard your data on multiple Redis instances if needed.

You will likely saturate the network links before the CPU of the Redis server. That's why it is better to implement the last value queue (if needed) on client side rather than server side.

Regarding the sum computation, I would try to calculate and maintain it in real time. For instance, the GETSET command can be used to set a new value while returning the previous one.

Instead of just setting your values, you could do:

```
[old value] = GETSET item <new value>
INCRBY mysum [new value] - [old value]
```

The mysum key will contain the sum of your values for all the items at any time. With Redis 2.6, you can use Lua to encaspulate this calculation to save roundtrips.

Running a big batch to calculate statistics on existing data (this is how I understand your "parallel" sum) is not really suitable for Redis. It is not designed for map/reduce like computation.

Comment: Yeah it's not the CPU I'm worried about but the network links. I'm going to be running this app in a cloud hosted environment and the sales rep told me their cloud instances only get 100MB/s which seems pitiful.

Comment: With a synchronous protocol I think last value queue on client side is the best option as you suggested. I was afraid the protocol would be async in which case this would be more difficult.